# SUM of quantity for each different unit (kg, pal, m^3)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm looking for a XSL script that will return back the sum of each different quantity in this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<output>
    <orders>
        <order>
            <id>1</id>
            <number>10002</number>
            <type>Loading</type>
            <date>2013-01-01T02:30:00</date>
        </order>
        <order>
            <id>2</id>
            <number>10003</number>
            <type>Loading</type>
            <date>2013-01-01T010:30:00</date>
        </order>
        <order>
            <id>3</id>
            <number>10004</number>
            <type>Loaded</type>
            <date>2013-01-01T12:30:00</date>
        </order>
    </orders>
    <quantities>
        <quantity>
            <id_order>1</id_order>
            <unit>KG</unit>
            <value>1000</value>
        </quantity>
        <quantity>
            <id_order>1</id_order>
            <unit>PAL</unit>
            <value>3</value>
        </quantity>
        <quantity>
            <id_order>1</id_order>
            <unit>M3</unit>
            <value>1.5</value>
        </quantity>
        <quantity>
            <id_order>2</id_order>
            <unit>KG</unit>
            <value>2000</value>
        </quantity>
        <quantity>
            <id_order>2</id_order>
            <unit>PAL</unit>
            <value>4</value>
        </quantity>
        <quantity>
            <id_order>3</id_order>
            <unit>KG</unit>
            <value>5000</value> 
        </quantity>
    </quantities>
</output>
```

I need the total quantities for PAL, the quantities for KG and for M3.
I've tried everything but the only think I can solve is to find the total quantity of everything, not differenciate by unit of measurment.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: [How to do sum having Group By using XSLT 1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709888/how-to-do-sum-having-group-by-using-xslt-1-0?rq=1) ?

Comment: Are you completely, positively sure you are restricted to XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 1.0, something like...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:key name="kDistinctUnit" match="quantity" use="unit"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- just skip to test bit -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//quantities"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="quantities">
    <xsl:for-each select="quantity[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('kDistinctUnit',unit))]">
        <xsl:value-of select="unit"/>
        <xsl:text> = </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kDistinctUnit',unit)/value)"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or in XSLT 2.0, something like...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- just skip to test bit -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//quantities"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="quantities">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="quantity" group-by="unit">
        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        <xsl:text> = </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/value)"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: But I get the sneaking suspicion that you may want to get the total quantities for each order?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="quantities">
        <xsl:text>KG: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="sum(//value[contains(preceding-sibling::*[1][name()='unit'], 'KG')])"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>PAL: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="sum(//value[contains(preceding-sibling::*[1][name()='unit'], 'PAL')])"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>M3: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="sum(//value[contains(preceding-sibling::*[1][name()='unit'], 'M3')])"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="orders"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your other questions around this particular problem, hopefully the following XSLT 1.0 should give all the bits you may need...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="kDistinctUnit" match="quantity" use="unit"/>
<xsl:key name="kDistinctUnitByOrder" match="quantity" use="concat(id_order,'||',unit)"/>
<xsl:key name="kQuantityByOrder" match="quantity" use="id_order"/>

<xsl:template match="order">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@* | *"/>
        <!-- totals for this order -->
        <xsl:variable name="vOrderId" select="id"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('kQuantityByOrder', $vOrderId)[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('kDistinctUnitByOrder', concat($vOrderId,'||',unit)))]">
            <xsl:element name="{unit}">
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kDistinctUnitByOrder', concat($vOrderId,'||',unit))/value)"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- show total quantities, by unit, across all orders -->
<xsl:template match="quantities">
    <total_quantities>
        <xsl:for-each select="quantity[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('kDistinctUnit',unit))]">
            <xsl:element name="{unit}">
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kDistinctUnit',unit)/value)"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </total_quantities>
</xsl:template>

<!-- identity transform stuff -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | text() | comment() | processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```